# Having Problems in retrieving Images from ParseUser

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want to retrieve images from default User class from Parse.com.  I only want values from the column named "Image".

```
ParseUser currentuser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("following");
query.whereEqualTo("username", currentuser);

try {
    ob = query.find();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

"Image" is the column name.

```
for (ParseObject user : ob) {
    // Locate images in pic column
    image = (ParseFile) user.get("Image");
}
```

How can I apply a loop to get all image files in a list?

```
image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
     public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {
             Bitmap pictureBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

             img.setImageBitmap(pictureBitMap);

             listView.setAdapter(new myCustomList(MainActivity.this));
         } else {
             // something went wrong
         }
     } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an open source library such as [Universal Image Loader(UIL)](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) so you wouldn't have to do the heavy lifting of downloading the file converting it to Bitmap and setting it to an imageView.

Basically you can retrieve the url from parseFile

```
String url = parseFile.getUrl();
```

And in UIL simply pass the url and the imageView

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```